# How do I get the type to convert to when deserializing from Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jodatime

It's trivial to generically serialize any type (e.g. a Joda `DateTime`) by delegating to [Joda Convert](http://www.joda.org/joda-convert/) like this:

```
public class ToJodaConverter extends SerializerBase<Object> {
    protected ToJodaConverter() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(StringConvert.INSTANCE.convertToString(value));
    }
}
```

I'd like to deserialize in the same way, something like this:

```
public class FromJodaConverter extends StdDeserializer<Object> {
    protected FromJodaConverter() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return StringConvert.INSTANCE.convertFromString(TYPE, jp.getText());
    }
}
```

But how do I get the TYPE that should be converted to? I've been searching for other subclasses of `JsonDeserializer`, but couldn't find out how to do this, or how to just implement the other `deserialize` method with the type parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the type you want to deserialize to:

```
public class FromJodaConverter<T> extends StdDeserializer<T> {
    public FromJodaConverter(Class<T> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return StringConvert.INSTANCE.convertFromString(handledType(), jp.getText());
    }
}
```

So, to create a FromJodaConverter that deserializes instances of Foo, you would use

```
new FromJodaConverter(Foo.class);
```

And to create a FromJodaConverter that deserializes instances of Baz, you would use

```
new FromJodaConverter(Baz.class);
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that I'm using `@JsonDeserialize` annotations in a JAX-RS container. I can't use instances of my converter, can I?